# Determine the Galois group of $x^3 + 3x^2 - 1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, galois-extensions

So the only possible roots in $\mathbb{Q}$ are $1$ or $-1$ and neither are roots. So all I rely know is that the group is isomorphic to $S_3$ or $A_3$ and the polynomial has no rational roots.

Also this problem is very similar to this problem
[Galois groups of $x^3-3x+1$ and $(x^3-2)(x^2+3)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1810055/galois-groups-of-x3-3x1-and-x3-2x23-over-mathbbq)
So I am trying to apply the answer for this question, but to be honest I am not sure what the discriminate means?

Comment: Google will find you lots of information about the rational root theorem and about discriminants, particularly if you spell the latter correctly.

Comment: @RobArthan looked up the rational root theorem and realized that was just the name of the theorem I used to find that there were no rational roots.

Comment: So I found this about the discriminate https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2019/07/14/discriminant-of-a-cubic/

Comment: The point is that the splitting field of $f$ contains, as a quadratic subfield, the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\Delta(f)})$ where $\Delta(f)$ is the discriminant of $f$. Can you figure out why it suffices for you to show that $\Delta(f)$ is not a square?

Comment: So in my case would the discriminate be $0 + 108 + 0 - 0  - 27 = 81$ So since $81$ is a square in $\mathbb{Q} $, the Galois group is $A_3$?

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but it will save you trouble if you learn it's called and spelled "discrimina**nt**".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$P(x) = x^3 + 3x^2 - 1$$

First of all lets check that $P(x)$ is irreducible. If it factors at all it will have a linear factor. So we can show it is irreducible by showing it has no rational roots, this is done with the rational root theorem.

This is a degree 3 irreducible polynomial so the Galois group will be $S_3$ or $C_3$.

One tool that we can use to differentiate between these two Galois groups is the discriminant:
$$\operatorname{disc}(x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d) = 18abcd - 4b^3d + b^2c^2 - 4ac^3 - 27a^2d^2$$.
The Galois group will be $C_3$ if and only if the discriminant is a square.

In our case the discriminant is $81 = 9^2$ so the Galois group is $C_3$.

Answer (score 4):

Substituting $x=y-1$ for $x$ yields the well-known equation $y^3-3y+1=0$, whose roots are $2cos(2\pi n/9)$ for $n=1, 4, 7$. This equation has Galois Group $A_3$; in fact, if a root is $\alpha$, then the other two roots are $\alpha ^2-2$ and $2-\alpha-\alpha ^2$, showing that adding $\alpha$ to the rationals also adds the other two roots.